# Trouble with Playwright with MUI and waiting for MUI Grid Data to Load

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, playwright, browser-automation, playwright-test

So I have three tests so far. First test is login and second test is to click the accounts tab. Both of these work fine. My third test(Account Details Contact Grid) is where I am having an issue. Upon click of accounts tab it goes to `baseUrl/accounts` and here it loads an MUI Grid with rows of data being requested from api. I am having trouble selecting the account link in one of these rows to go to account details. I can't tell if I should `page.waitForUrl`, `page.waitForLoadState` or something else or if I am even using `page.waitForURL` correctly with regex. But essentially I want the the grid with data to load and be able to click on an account but it keeps giving me error timeout

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test'
import config from './.auth/config.json'
import { Login } from './utils'

test.describe('Account Details', () => {
  let context
  let page
  let login

  test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
    context = await browser.newContext()
    page = await context.newPage()
    login = new Login(page)
    await login.loginApp(config.brokerUsername, config.brokerPassword)
  })

  test('Select accounts from sidemenu', async () => {
    await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle')
    const accountsButton = await page
      .getByTestId('accounts')
      .getByRole('button')
    await accountsButton.click()
  })

  test('Account Details Contacts Grid', async () => {
    // await page.waitForURL(new RegExp('/accounts$'))
    // await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle')
    await expect(page.getByRole('link', { name: 'AccuDock' })).toHaveText(
      'AccuDock'
    )
    await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'AccuDock' }).click()
    // await page.getByRole('tab', { name: 'Contacts (1)' }).click()
    // await page
    //   .getByText('Corporate Office123 S 11TH StSan Jose, CA 951122133Primary')
    //   .click()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `page.waitForURL()` method waits for the "load" event by default.

In cases where page is not ready, it must be doing some async behavior like calling some APIs to get some data. In these scenarios it's usually best to wait for something visual on the page that loads last, for example:

```
await page.waitForURL(/expectedURLOrItsSubstring/);
await page.locator('text=Item that loads in the last on page').waitFor()
```